# Eclipse starting error of JVM terminated. Exit code=13 after upgrading Ubuntu updates

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I've just updated Ubuntu and then Eclipse crashed. Does anyone know a solution? Otherwise I have to re-install the things.

[image: jvm terminated]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9636283/405117 helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just install "Open JDK" and it fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: This also worked for me, I was attempting to use Jaspersoft Studio on Ubuntu (worked great for a while, then died [maybe from updates]).

I installed the latest Open JDK from http://openjdk.java.net/install/ and had to make a symbolic link from the included JDK in Jaspersoft Studio to the Open JDK

Command was "ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre jre"  FROM the "jaspersoftstudio-5.1.0/features/jre.linux.gtk.x86_64.feature_1.7.0.u25/jre" directory

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://www.ehow.com/how_4784069_terminated-exit-code-error-eclipse.html. And also look in the workspace log file

Comment: I did not finding JRE directory for :"./eclipse -vm /home/'MY_ACCOUNT'/app/jre1.5.0_10/bin"
Where I can find the JRE  directory????

Comment: Type java -version in a shell. What does it answer ?

Comment: It says :java version "1.6.0_20". I don't know where is its directory. I also check the hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem after changing my jvm.cfg file. I did this to make my maven builds faster.

The change was to swap around:
-server KNOWN
-client KNOWN

I changed this back, the error disappeared.