# Error starting Eclipse in Linux: "JVM terminated. Exit code=13"

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am trying to run eclipse and encounter the errors. I am using Kubuntu as my OS and when I typed `java -version` in terminal I got 'java version "1.6.0_23"'. I have openJDK installed but I am not sure what can I do next. Any thoughts? Thanks.

ERROR:

```
   JVM terminated. Exit code=13
    /usr/bin/java
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx384m
    -jar /home/lucky/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
    -os linux
    -ws gtk
    -arch x86
    -showsplash
    -    launcher /home/lucky/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse
    -name Eclipse
    --launcher.library /home/lucky/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345/eclipse_1310.so
    -startup /home/lucky/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
    -exitdata 5cf8058
    -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
    -vm /usr/bin/java
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx384m
    -jar /home/lucky/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
```

My eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

Comment: Related? [http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945178/72178](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945178/72178)

Comment: please try using the eclipse from ubuntu repositories. this will make your life a lot easier :)

Comment: I forget my ubuntu repositories. lol. Can't shake off the bad habit after using Windows in the pass 2 weeks. Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Looking at the paths in the error it seems that you are not using eclipse from the ubuntu repositories (that's fine imo).

1. Check if the jvm is 64 or 32 bit. `java -version` will tell you. If you find this is a 64-bit jvm then go back to eclipse.org and download a eclipse version for *64-bit*. You have eclipse for a 32-bit jvm. See your error message where it says `-arch x86`
2. Try to start eclipse from a shell using the `-vm` parameter. On ubuntu you can find the installed jre/jdk's under `/var/lib/jvm/`. E.g.:

`./eclipse -vm /var/lib/jvm/sun-java6-jdk/bin`

You could add this parameter to your eclipse.ini file.

Helps?

This could be of interest as well: [Eclipse starting error of JVM terminated. Exit code=13 after upgrading Ubuntu updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844249/eclipse-starting-error-of-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13-after-upgrading-ubuntu-up)

Comment: Just one shot useful!! Thumbs Up !!

Answer (score 7):

I have found solution for errors 13 and 1 in following video:

[Eclipse Error 13 and Error 1](https://youtu.be/oI_qPnA753Q)

Both errors are fixed by editing eclipse.ini in eclipse directory.

Error 13 is fixed by adding complete path to javaw. In my case it is:

```
-vm
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

Error 1 is caused by setting arguments for virtual machine before setting vm. itself.
This means two lines we just added must be before the

```
-vmargs
```

line.

Done.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Specify the JVM you want to use in your eclipse.ini file, as described in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

I'd recommend using the JDK from Oracle; I'm not sure the current state of compatibility between Eclipse and OpenJDK.

Comment: Eclipse and OpenJDK work fine. I am using the same. Of course, I used the package from Ubuntu repositories ..

Comment: The program I was trying to use did not read from the 'eclipse.ini', came with an included JDK, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7074464/1606846

Answer (score 1):

This might sound a little odd but I have stumbled upon the same problem (StS 3.2.2 on Juno 4.2.2 with Java 7 u25 both 64 bit on win7) and nothing seemed to work, then I moved my sts out of the directory I originally installed it (d:#sts\springsource\sts-3.2.0.RELEASE) to (d:\springsource\sts-3.2.0.RELEASE), and now it works. 
I kept it in both places and if I want to start it from its original location it promptly crashes with exit code 13, if I start it from the new place it works just fine.

So it might be that eclipse does not like hash marks, or it was "too far away" from root and some of the files paths-es went beyond 256 char. (Nonetheless its quite odd the get exit code 13 since in my case it had nothing to do with non-matching versions)

Comment: I had the same exact problem on Linux. I fixed by moving it closer to the root folder. There seems to be a character for file paths limit on some plugin that STS uses! Thank you random user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

I got through with the following:

```
which java
```

It gave me :`/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25/bin/java`

I went to the folder where eclipse was located (~/Developer/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140624/eclipse/ in my case )

```
 cd ~/Developer/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140624/eclipse/
```

Then

```
  ./eclipse -vm /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25/bin
```

You can make this permanent by editing the eclipse.ini file:
Right after OpenFile I inserted 2 lines containing:

```
 -vm

 /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25/bin/java
```

The second line being the output from the `which java` command.

Now Eclipse loads for me but it misbehaves, hopefully not related.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my windows 8.1 machine. All the suggestions didn't fix my issue.
I then thought about the root cause. I believed it was caused by degrading from JDK-9 to JDK-8. I recently uninstalled JDK-9.
I went and checked the Environment Variable-->Path and it contained another Java reference of "**C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath**".

I simply **removed this extra "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" from Path**(environment variable), and My Eclipse worked.

I hope this helps others.