# Eclipse Download on Ubuntu error

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I just downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop, and I'm trying to run Eclipse. When I downloaded it and tried to run it, it told me to install JRE, so I did. But now it's showing this error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/sam/Eclipse/eclipse//plugin/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/sam/Eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/sam/Eclipse/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/sam/Eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835/eclipse_1506.so
-startup /home/sam/Eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata e5800c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/sam/Eclipse/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

I'm very new to Ubuntu and I'm not sure at all what is going on. Did something install incorrectly? Is something not installed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does /usr/bin/Java exist ?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse did you download? Which JRE did you install?

Comment: @user1281385 - I don't know. Like I said, I'm VERY new to Ubuntu.

Comment: @escitalopram - The newest version of Eclipse (4.3.1, I think), and openjdk-7-jre on [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java).

Comment: What does stat /usr/bin/java show

Comment: maybe one of those helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635506/error-starting-eclipse-in-linux-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13/9636283#9636283 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

Comment: @user1281385
`  File: ‘/usr/bin/java’ -> ‘/etc/alternatives/java’`
`  Size: 22         Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   ``symbolic link`
`Device: 807h/2055d Inode: 2629811     Links: 1`
`Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)`
`Access: 2013-10-06 16:18:28.550738188 -0400`
`Modify: 2013-10-06 16:07:09.426732491 -0400`
`Change: 2013-10-06 16:07:09.526732492 -0400`
` Birth: -`

Comment: @escitalopram - I just tried installing the 32-bit version of Eclipse, but that seems to show the exact same error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to run the 32 bit version of Eclipse with a 64 bit Java. You need to use the 64 bit version of Eclipse.

Comment: Actually, this was the error I got when I tried to run the 64 bit version of Eclipse. I tried the 32 bit afterwards, and it still has the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install Eclipse Standard 4.3.1 (from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads) on ArchLinux.

Here is the version of my java installation:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.2) (ArchLinux build 7.u40_2.4.2-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

...and got exactly the same error.