# Eclipse installation on Linux Mint 17

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run Eclipse Luna 4.4 on Linux Mint 17 Qiana.

i already downloaded and extracted the tar.gz file under /opt/eclipse folder and i get the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Eclipse:
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 4e0018
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

My computer is 32 bits and i downloaded x86 Eclipse 4.4
Have someone encountered this same problem?

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed? What are the results of `java -version` and `update-java-alternatives -l`?

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635506/error-starting-eclipse-in-linux-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) seems related. Might it be 64bit vs 32bit issue? First line in your output, "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server".

Comment: The computer is 32 bits but looks like java is 64 bit. should i install java 32 or just eclipse 64 bit?