# Can not install IBM installation manager on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, ibm-installation-manager

i have a problem when i tried to install IBM installation manager into CentOS 6.5.
i tried to install all version of IBM installation manager (both remote from window and on GUI mode), but the same error occurred.

in command line

```
Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display "localhost:11.0"
```

in GUI (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9s1D.jpg)

```
Install:
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/ftp/im//jre_6.0.0.sr9_20110208_03/jre/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xquickstart
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-jar /ftp/im/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /ftp/im/install
-name Install
--launcher.library /ftp/im/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /ftp/im/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 18000
-toolId install
-accessRights admin input @osgi.install.area/install.xml
-vm /ftp/im//jre_6.0.0.sr9_20110208_03/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xquickstart
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-jar /ftp/im/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

follow google, i also tried to config X11 forwarding, GTK, change JRE path from install.ini file, use console mode, but i still received those error.

can somebody give me a solution?

thanks

Comment: Did you install all required libraries defined in [Preparing Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 for installation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/tins_linuxsetup_rhel6.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-5-0-4-2-2&lang=en)?

Comment: yes, i installed all. i think CentOS may not compatible

Comment: There's no centos compatibility issue.

Comment: Try these properties? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI29110

Comment: thanks you, i installed cairo 1.9.6, but i still received that error. i tried redhat too, but the same error

Comment: This of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635506/error-starting-eclipse-in-linux-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13/9636283#9636283

Comment: i don't get any problem when start eclipse GUI. i also know IBM installation manager use eclipse to build it's GUI. but it's still not working.