# “JVM terminated. Exit code=13” Error starting Eclipse in Linux with 64-bit and using -vm parameter

Tags: linux, eclipse

I get the following error when I try to start eclipse in linux. My JRE version seems correct and the OS 64 bit is correct as well. I have read solutions to this issue posted by others and tried them, but I still get the problem. Any help to solve is problem is appreciated.

$ which java
/opt/tools/wh/dtd/RHE-6/jdk/1.5.0_22/bin/java

$ uname -a
[snip] Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I started eclipse with the vm option
./eclipse -vm /opt/tools/wh/dtd/RHE-6/jdk/1.5.0_22/bin

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/opt/tools/wh/dtd/RHE-6/jdk/1.5.0_22/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-jar /localdisk/nevi/tools/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /localdisk/nevi/tools/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /localdisk/nevi/tools/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345/eclipse_1310.so
-startup /localdisk/nevi/tools/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-exitdata 108003
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /opt/tools/wh/dtd/RHE-6/jdk/1.5.0_22/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-jar /localdisk/nevi/tools/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked. From the answers there I found this:

> Check if the jvm is 64 or 32 bit.
>   "java -version" will tell you. If you find this is a 64-bit jvm then go back to eclipse.org and download an eclipse version for 64-bit. You have eclipse for a 32-bit jvm. See your error message where it says -arch x86
>
> Try to start eclipse from a shell using the -vm parameter. On ubuntu you can find the installed jre/jdk's under /var/lib/jvm/. E.g.:
>   ./eclipse -vm /var/lib/jvm/sun-java6-jdk/bin

This is the original thread: [Error starting Eclipse in Linux: "JVM terminated. Exit code=13"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635506/error-starting-eclipse-in-linux-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: the jvm is 64 and the eclipse version is 64-bit. As indicated in the question. I also tried to start eclipse using the -vm parameter and it did not work either.